# A graph that helps understand DGP of a mixture of Gaussians (DAG, Kruschke's DBDA style graph, etc.)?

Tags: dag, causal-diagram

Hastie, et al in “Elements of Statistical Learning” describe a particular DGP(Data Generating Process) or causal model on page 13.

> The training data in each class (2 classes total) came from a mixture of 10 low variance Gaussian distributions, with individual means themselves distributed as Gaussian. A mixture of Gaussians is best described in terms of the generative model. One first generates a discrete variable which determines which of the component Gaussians to use, and then generates an observation from the chosen density.

Having learned most of what I know about DAG’s from Pearl’s Primer book, which does not include a mixture as an example, I am just not sure what a DAG would look like in this case.

John Kruschke, in his book "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" offers an attractive alternative to DAGs, which show a sketch of the distribution indexed by its parameters. See [here](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2013/10/diagrams-for-hierarchical-models-we.html) and [here](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/05/graphical-model-diagrams-in-doing.html). So if you prefer to do a DBDA style plot over the DAG, that works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're drawing a DAG of the variable you have measured in this scenario, it's just the two of them: `Class` affects `Data`.

[image]

If you're representing the mixture process (which depends on the unobserved choice of `Component`):

[image]

This isn't a very satisfying answer, but that's because DAGs don't represent the details of the generative model, just the presence of dependencies.

[Image source](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rankdir%3DLR%0A%20%20%20%20Component%5Bshape%3D%22rectangle%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20Class%20-%3E%20Component%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Component%20-%3E%20Data%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Class%20-%3E%20Data%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Why is class causing data? That doesn't seem right. The DGP describes a separate mixture of tightly clustered Gaussians for the 2 classes. In my mind we use the DAG because it is helpful/informative. I would like to think the DAG would accommodate this scenario; if not, perhaps Krushske's DBDA style graph might. But I would like to think there is a graph that adds value to our understanding our the DGP. And that is what I am looking for here.

Comment: Why is class causing data? Because the value of `Data` for a given data point depends on what class that data point belongs to. I'm not sure what else you're looking for, DAGs are tools for showing dependencies, and these are the dependencies in the mixture example.

Comment: Maybe you are correct and this is the best we can do with regards to mapping this DGP. I'll let others, more knowledgeable in this than me, help me decide that.

Comment: I will take others' silence to mean that there isn't much more we can do here. The DAG you drew maybe all we can convey about this mixture. So I will award you the answer. On the other hand, I will interpret the few votes your answer has received as a general agreement with your own assertion that this DAG is not very satisfying. In my mind, this takes nothing away from your effort but is a statement about the shortcomings of a DAG. Thank you.